# create database for android application

Tags: android, database

I am developing an android application that would help general public to get information on bus routes in Mumbai.

I am facing a problem of how should I create a database (design) so that when user enters a source and destination stop, it should return the corresponding bus numbers for that route.
there are around 2000 bus stops and 750 buses running,....

I have all the data in .csv files..like for each bus its entire route..but still confused on how should i go about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have like

```
 Bus_details:
   bus_id
   other_bus _details
   .....
 station_details:
    station_id
    station
    ....
 route_details:
   route_id 
   route (stationid1,stationid2,...,stationidn) //separated by character

 schedule_details:
   Bus_id
   route_id
   day
   month
   time
```

you can also have distance between stations and time

Comment: how would i fire a query if i want to find all buses running between a particular bus stop. (just have basic to intermediate knowledge of sql).. the (stationid1,stationid2...) is a confusing part for me....

Comment: i am no database expert :), but this should work, 'select bus_id,schedule.route_id from schedule join route_details on schedule.route_id = route_details.route_id where route_details.route like '%stationid1,stationid2%' ;  .... I mean, we can fetch results with 'like' operator.

Comment: ohhhh..i will try this and definetly reply,..thanks a lot for helping

Comment: k. all the best.. also you can have any combination e.g., route is 'st6,st7,st8,st9,st10' then if you want to find bus bet'n say st7 and st9, simply with like '%st7%,st9% this will give results. also you look at [link](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models). /index.htm